# MYSQL group by and counting columns

Tags: mysql

Say I have a table like this:

```
+--------+-------+
|  ID    | LETTER|
+--------+-------+
|  1     |   A   |
|  1     |   A   |
|  1     |   A   |
|  2     |   A   |
|  2     |   B   |
|  3     |   C   |
|  3     |   D   |
|  4     |   D   |
+--------+-------+
```

How would I implement a query that returns the ID followed by how many unique letters it has? So it would look like this:

```
+--------+-------+
|  ID    | LETTER|
+--------+-------+
|  1     |   1   |
|  2     |   2   |
|  3     |   2   |
|  4     |   1   |
+--------+-------+
```

I've tried using group by but I cant figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You should search for the answer before questioning. But here is what you need:

```
SELECT yt.ID, COUNT(DISTINCT yt.LETTER)
FROM yourtable yt
GROUP BY yt.ID
```